# Bounding $2$-simplexes in punctured plane in $\Bbb R^2 - \{0\}$ intuition

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology concerning developing the intuition on homology functors:

> The question we ask is whether a union of $n$-smplexes in $X$ actually is such a boundary.  Consider the case $n=1.$  Let $X$ be the punctured plane $\Bbb R^2 - \{0\}$, and let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be the $1$-simplexes as drawn (the picture shows a triangle with the origin missing inside the triangle with edges $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$  oriented counter-clockwise); ***$\alpha \cup \beta \cup \gamma$ "ought" to bound the triangular $2$-simplex, but the absence of the origin prevents this;  loosely speaking, $X$ has a "one-dimensional" hole in it.  (Of course, $\alpha \cup \beta \cup \gamma$ would not bound the triangular $2$-simplex if $X$ were missing a small neighborhood of the origin or a small line segment through the origin).***

How does $T = \alpha \cup \beta \cup \gamma$ NOT bound the triangular $2$-simplex?  Isn't all of the triangular $2$-simplex within $T$?  If you just fill in the inside of $T$ shouldn't you get the triangular $2$-simplex? And even if you take out lines through and neighborhoods of the origin doesn't this still bound the $2$-simplex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course *abstractly* $T$ bounds the $2$-simplex $\Delta^2$, but not *in $X$*. There is no subspace of $X$ homeomorphic to $\Delta^2$ which is bounded by $T$.